# Deleting nodes from xml with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file. It contains records as in the example below.

```
<Simulator>
  <Flight ID="1" Description="1sunny" Date="2022-09-09">
    <Instructor Num="6">
      <Name>matt</Name>
      <Surname>matt</Surname>
      <Rank>matt</Rank>
    </Instructor>
  </Flight>
</Simulator>
```

When I delete it with the delete function, I see such a result and this result breaks my auto generate id function. How can I get the flight tag to be deleted completely?

```
<Simulator>
  <Flight />
</Simulator>
```

---

Delete function

```
private void b_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(input);
            foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("Flight"))
            {
                foreach (var attr in elem.Attributes("ID"))
                {
                    if (attr.Value.Equals("1"))
                        elem.RemoveAll();
                }
            }
            xDoc.Save(input);
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
        }
```

Comment: What is the result you want? Just the `Simulator` tag?

Comment: if there is no more record(like id="2"), then <Simulator></Simulator>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, you can get the right element with the LINQ `Where` extension method. This is the reason why the `XDocument` stuff is in the [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=net-6.0)

(I am using C# 11's raw string feature for this test):

```cs
string xml = """
    <Simulator>
        <Flight ID="1" Description="1sunny" Date="2022-09-09">
            <Instructor Num="6">
                <Name>matt</Name>
                <Surname>matt</Surname>
                <Rank>matt</Rank>
            </Instructor>
        </Flight>
    </Simulator>
    """;
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

xDoc.Root?.Descendants("Flight")
    .Where(f => f.Attribute("ID")?.Value == "1")
    .Remove();

Console.WriteLine(xDoc);
```

Prints:

```
<Simulator />
```

IntelliSense told me that `Root` and `Attribute("ID")` can be null. Therefore I used the [C# Null-Conditional Operator (? Operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

If you want to remove only one element, you can speed up the process by using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`:

```cs
xDoc.Root?.Descendants("Flight")
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Attribute("ID")?.Value == "1")
    ?.Remove();
```

This will stop looping at the first element found. This requires another `?` as `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if no matching element was found, whereas `Where` returns an empty enumeration.

Note that with `Where` we are using

```cs
public static void Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source) where T : XNode;
```

with `T` as `XElement`, but with `FirstOrDefault` we call the `XNode.Remove();` method.

Comment: Nice detail to use "?" sign. The code gave the output I wanted, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Remove` extension methodon result of `Descendants` method:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xDoc = XDocument.Load(input);

xDoc.Document.Descendants("Flight")
    .Remove();

using var writer = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Append);

xDoc.Save(writer);
```